# Python flask and AngularJS with Chaining http post Requests Sequentially

Tags: angularjs, ajax, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to split data into chunks, which are then sent to Python flask via AngularJS `$http.post` calls. On the JS side, it seems that the requests are being issued in the given order. But on the Python side, the requests don't seem to be arriving with the intended order.

The temporary code looks something like this:

JS:

```
var xdata = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "***__END__***"].map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
var post_chain = [];
for (var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++) {
    post_chain.push($http.post("/path", xdata[i]));
}

post_chain[0].then(function (response0) {
    console.log("response0");
    return post_chain[1];
}).then(function (response1) {
    console.log("response1");
    return post_chain[2];
}).then(function (response2) {
    console.log("response2");
    return post_chain[3];
}).then(function (response3) {
    console.log("response3");
    return post_chain[4];
}).then(function (response4) {
    console.log("response4");
    return post_chain[5];
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('Done');
    // Handle response
});
```

In Python, I use `flask.request.get_json(silent=False)` to get the input data. There's some code to detect a termination criterion (e.g., given by the string `"***__END__***"`) signaling the end of posts from JS. This is why I need to ensure the order of the requests from JS to Python. I also print out the received data.

The console output in JS looks fine (it shows 0, 1, 2, etc. in the given order). But in Python, the printed data is out of order (0, 4, 1, etc.).

Later on, I intend to generalize the JS code with a recursive function, for example. But for now, I'm trying to guarantee that the Python code receives data in the correct order.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

The suggestions work! However, the ideal approach is to generalize the code for any array size. I think this can be done with recursion, but it doesn't seem to be passing the data in the right order. What's missing?

```
var post_chain_call = function(i, post_element) {
    if (i == post_chain.length - 1) {
        return post_element(xdata[i]).then(function (response) {
            // Handle response
        });
    } else {
        return post_element(xdata[i]).then(post_chain_call(i + 1, post_chain[i + 1]));
    }
}
post_chain_call(0, post_chain[0]);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Got it to work with another approach!

```
var post_chain_call = function(i, post_element) {
    if (i == post_chain.length - 1) {
        return post_element.then(function (response) {
            // Handle response
        });
    } else {
        return post_element.then(function (response_tmp) {
            return post_chain_call(i + 1, post_chain[i + 1](xdata[i + 1]));
        });
    }
}
post_chain_call(0, post_chain[0](xdata[0]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment your front-end starts communicating with the back-end is when you're assigning them to `postChain`. This means that each of the requests on their own are attempting to communicate with the server, and the order in which they connect to the server cannot be predicted. A possible workaround to make sure a request is only *instantiated* in the `.then()` of the previous request would be to not store the result of the `$http.post()` call in the chain, but instead a function that executed `$http.post()` and returns that promise.

```
    var xdata = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "***__END__***"].map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
    var post_chain = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++) {
        // this way, the code is not yet executed, but it will when you call it.
        post_chain.push((data) => $http.post("/path", data));
    }

    post_chain[0](xdata[0]).then(function (response0) {
        console.log("response0");
        return post_chain[1](xdata[1]);
    }).then(function (response1) {
        console.log("response1");
        return post_chain[2](xdata[2]);
    }).then(function (response2) {
        console.log("response2");
        return post_chain[3](xdata[3]);
    }).then(function (response3) {
        console.log("response3");
        return post_chain[4](xdata[4]);
    }).then(function (response4) {
        console.log("response4");
        return post_chain[5](xdata[5]);
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('Done');
        // Handle response
    });
```

You can also use arrow functions to make sure `xdata` is still in the function scope and you don't need to pass any arguments to it

```
    var post_chain = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++) {
        // this way, the code is not yet executed, but it will when you call it.
        post_chain.push(() => $http.post("/path", xdata[i]));
    }
    post_chain[0]().then((response0) => {
        console.log("response0");
        return post_chain[1]();
    }).then((response1) => {
        console.log("response1");
        return post_chain[2]();
    }).then((response2) => {
        console.log("response2");
        return post_chain[3]();
    }).then((response3) => {
        console.log("response3");
        return post_chain[4]();
    }).then((response4) => {
        console.log("response4");
        return post_chain[5]();
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('Done');
        // Handle response
    });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Mmmm.... on the Python side, `flask.request.get_json(silent=False)` returns `None`. It doesn't seem to be receiving the contents of `xdata`.

Comment: Your suggestion works if I make the following changes: `post_chain.push(x => $http.post(urlPrefix() + "/api/"+caller+"/export", x));` and then pass each `xdata[i]` in the parentheses, for example, `post_chain[0](xdata[0])`, etc.

Comment: Good point, sorry about that. You can also replace the functions in the callback with arrow notation, then `xdata` should be available in the local scope. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to generalize the `.then()` calls for any number of calls using recursion. I updated my question. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Done! Updated my post. Thanks for the help!